# Prime integer multiplication table c++

Tags: c++

I'm relatively new to c++ and coding and general and I was wondering how I would be able to produce a prime integer multiplication table up to 20. This is what I tried so far.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void table() {
    int var;
    for(int x = 1; x <= 20; x++) {
        for(int y = 1; y <= 20;y++) {
            for (int i = x*y; i <= x*y; i++) {
                if (i == 1 || i == 0) 
                    continue;  
                var = 1; 
                for (int j = 2; j <= i / 2; ++j) {
                    if (i % j == 0) {
                          var = 0; 
                          break; 
                    } 
                }  
            }                  
            if (x * y % 2 != 0 && x * y % 3 != 0){
                cout << x * y << "\t";   
            }  
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    table();
    return 0;
}
```

I've managed to produce prime integers of 5 and above, but I don't know how to produce the integer 2 and 3. I also don't know how to get rid of the 1 in the first column. Any feedback is much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I see 4 nested `for` loops in your code. You might want to take a step back and think about the algorithm you're trying to implement.

Comment: Please format your code. It's difficult to read.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `for (int i = x*y; i <= x*y; i++) `? That will loop exactly once and can be replaced with `int i = x*y;`.

Comment: @interjay The `continue` means the `if (i==0 || i==1) {` needs to be reversed as well...

Comment: If you want to get rid of the 1 that is printed in the upper right hand corner, try this: https://onlinegdb.com/SJOd_yavw

Comment: That loop that sets var to 1 or 0 doesn't do anything because var is never used - you probably meant to use it in the if statement that follows...  Since you aren't using it you can remove it and you get: https://onlinegdb.com/ryV5tk6vD

Comment: Then, finally, all you need a way to know if a linefeed should be printed and you end up with: https://onlinegdb.com/Hyq8skpPv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy method is to use a look up array or vector of the first 20 primes.  This will reduce the complexity of trying to find primes.  You can focus on the multiplication table instead.

```
const int primes[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23 /*, ... */};
for (int row = 0; row < sizeof(primes); ++row)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < sizeof(primes); ++column)
    {
        const int product = primes[row] * primes[column];
        std::cout << product << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

I recommend getting the table to print out correctly before using code to detect primes.  You can always add code to this that determines the primes and places them into the array.